# Languages free of concatenations of stars

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

[Union-free regular languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/8156/1993), defined by regular expressions (using $*$, literals (alphabet symbols), and concatenation) excluding union (written $+$ or $\cup$) have been studied.

Note that unions under a Kleene $*$ can always be eliminated:
$$(u+v)^*=(u^*v^*)^*.$$
Now, my question is about

> (preferably union-free) languages that can be defined by a regular expression not containing any subexpression of the form $u^*v^*$.

As an example, $0^*1^*$ is union-free (clearly) but I don't think it can be written without something of the form $u^*v^*$.

Have such languages been studied?

Comment: $u^*v^*=u^*+u^*vv^*$, so you can rewrite any regular expression not to have any subexpressions of this form.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Nice, this shows that we must restrict attention to the union-free case.